# (How) can I convert full-width characters to half-width ones?

Tags: unicode

I need to transform the full-width characters(`ＮＢＡ`) in the following sentence to half-width ones.

> ＮＢＡ中曾有“怒吼天尊”之称的已退役球员是谁? 拉希德·华莱士
>   Ｈ５Ｎ２疫苗可对抗Ｈ５禽流感病毒

I know I can realize it in Python using `unicodedata.normalize` module(with a parameter "NFKC"). But is there any method to do it directly in Vim? I have tried `char2nr` and `eval` and found that they don't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There you go:

```
:%s/[\uff01-\uff5e]/\=nr2char(char2nr(submatch(0))-65248)/g
```

This matches the range of full-width characters, and via `:help sub-replace-expr` and `char2nr()` converts this to a number, subtracts to get this into the ASCII range for `!` - `~`, and converts it back to characters.

#### Addendum

If you need to support other (non-contiguous) characters, you can define a Map and check that first. For example, for the arrow symbols mentioned in your comment:

```
let g:fullToHalf = { "\u2190": "\uFFE9", "\u2192": "\uFFEB", "\u2191": "\uFFEA", "\u2193": "\uFFEC" }
:execute '%s/[\uff01-\uff5e' . join(keys(g:fullToHalf), ''). ']/\=get(g:fullToHalf, submatch(0), nr2char(char2nr(submatch(0))-65248))/g'
```

Note: As a one-liner, this gets really ugly. I would strongly recommend to put this into a function.

Comment: Thanks very much again for your awesome answer. But any ideas for the half-width characters outside of the ASCII range? I mean especially for those with full-width characters of Unicode `[\uff5f-\uff65\uffda-\uffee]`? For example `￬` in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms_(Unicode_block)).

Comment: It can be done; I've extended my answer.

Comment: Any chance you can define a bash script version of this combined range and map approach to replace all full width characters with half width equivalents found in a file? I need to accomplish this in a stand alone bash script (not within vi or vim).

Comment: @Streamline You can invoke Vim non-interactively from a shell script. Usually it's better to use specialized tools like `sed` or `awk`, but this may be a valid case for Vim. For details, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235112/how-to-run-a-series-of-vim-commands-from-command-prompt).